# How to stop flask application propperly without ctrl-c after 10 seconds

Tags: python, flask

I would like to use Flask as a part of a python script. I would like to execute some commands then run a Flask server to send a file and after 10 seconds or more to close the server and contineue running the script.

After shut_down function is executed an error is appearing and the rest script does not executed untiil I press ctrl-c in terminal. Here is my code

```
from flask import send_from_directory, abort 
from flask import Flask
import socket
from flask import request
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler


hostName= socket.gethostname()
ipAddr= socket.gethostbyname(hostName)
app= Flask(__name__)
app.config["CLIENT_IMAGES"]="photo"

socketio = SocketIO(app)
sched=APScheduler()
counter=0

def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')    
    func()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"


@app.route("/get-image/<string:image_name>") 
def get_image(image_name):    
    try:
        return send_from_directory(app.config["CLIENT_IMAGES"], "photo.jpg", as_attachment=True)
        
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)

if __name__=="__main__":
    sched.add_job(id='Job1',func=shutdown_server, trigger='interval', seconds=5)
    sched.start()
    #app.run()
    #socketio.run(app,host="0.0.0.0", port=4998,allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
    app.run(host=ipAddr, port='5000',debug= False) #,use_reloader=False 
    #os.system("start /b python app.py")
    #os.system("python "+ "app.py &" )
counter+=1
print("ALohaaa")
```

Here is the error:

```
Job "Job1 (trigger: interval[0:00:05], next run at: 2023-10-09 09:59:57 EEST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userName\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\users\ userName \desktop\jetson\camera test\mix\qr prog test\try03.py", line 21, in shutdown_server
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ userName \anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 311, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ userName \anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 508, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: As a side note, the fact that you've decided to crush all the newlines out of your code makes it _really_ difficult to read. I don't know why you've done that but it helps nobody and it won't run any faster for reducing the lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose an endpoint that shutdown your flask app and call it by curl when you want to stop the app

```
@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
   print("Shutting down gracefully...")
   os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
   return 'Server shutting down...'
```

and call it like this with curl

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/shutdown
```

You can explore more options [HERE](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-do-i-terminate-a-flask-app-that-s-running-as-a-service).

Comment: Why not just call `sys.exit`?  Using signals is very Unix specific!

Comment: Thank you very much in the article I found the answer that works best for my case